# Recommend some C# Printing/Print Preview/Reporting Libraries?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, printing, datagridview, print-preview

I'm looking to outsource some of my work to a decent library. I'll provide some specifications for the library, and it would be a great help if I could get some references to the type of library I'm looking for.

**1 :  Can be free or paid.** But, must be able to be redistributed for my commercial application royalty free, and without any restrictions, other than paying for the initial library. Also, I'm trying to stay under $300~$400, if possible.

**2 :  Reporting services.** An easy way to create reports from dataGridView objects.

**3 :  Print Preview services.** An easy way to create a print preview from #2's reports.

**4 :  Printing services.** An easy way to print the print preview from #3, which assuming the library has print preview services, I can probably assume it has printing functions, just wanted to be sure.

And that's it! Thanks, as always, for any help (in this case references) you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two of them that come to my mind:

1. [Report Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) - free web and windows controls that can show either reports from SSRS or rdlc reports (local mode). Local mode will fit into your requirements
2. Crystal Reports for VS 2010. Redistribution for server application is not free (see http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/weblogs?blog=/pub/wlg/18828)

Now, I am not certain about your requirement #2 but AFAIK, it would be possible to bind the grid data to report to get the output.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but I appreciate the attempt.